# tinyos-2.1.1 intsallation in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, tinyos

I'm learning about Wireless Sensor Network in TinyOS. I tried to install this in Ubuntu 18.04 but it ain't worked and it return this kind of error (the picture included). Anyone could help me with this failure. Many thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZhtu.png

Comment: Hello. Please don't use screenshots for terminal output. Instead, copy the terminal output, paste it into your question, select it with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor. It will make your question much more readable and searchable.

Comment: For clarity, the OP's screenshot includes the following error messages: `sudo apt-get install tinyos-2.1.1` `The following packages have unmet dependencies` `tinyos-2.1.1 : Depends : tinyos-required-all but it is not going to be installed <more>` `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. The reason is that TinyOS is now relatively old (in software terms) and the original development community have largely moved onto other things. This means that the packages are no longer maintained, and thus there are issues with unmet and broken dependencies. These issues will only get more and more problematic as Ubuntu evolves and leaves these packages far behind.

I can't remember exactly what the problem is as it was some time ago, but thankfully I wrote up [a detailed explanation on how to install TinyOS on Vagrant here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/installing-tinyos-ubuntu-using-vagrant-james-allen). It was tested on Ubuntu 16.04 but it should also work on 18.04.

The TL;DR version is to look carefully at the bootstrap script I use. For example, try this (the first line adds a signing key to your package manager - this came directly from Eric Decker's package repo):

```
wget -O - http://tinyprod.net/repos/debian/tinyprod.key | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get -y install nesc tinyos-tools avr-tinyos msp430-46 mspdebug
```

For further info see the [official wiki](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Installing_TinyOS) and [Eric Decker's repo](http://tinyprod.net/repos/debian/), but these are also quite out of date now.